# How do i debug a device owner/device admin application?

Tags: android, xamarin, device-owner

I have a Xamarin Android app.  I have used ADB to make it a device owner.  I have also set it up so it requests DeviceAdministrator privileges.  When i try to run the app from visual studio it, using the same signing key it was created with, it fails on the deployment phase saying it cannot uninstall the application.  I know that DeviceAdmin privileges keep the app from uninstalling, but how does one then push from Visual Studio to debug the application?

Comment: maybe you could use ADB shell command to remove device owner,then run VS to install application

Comment: If i use ADB do make it not device owner, then use visual studio to install it, then visual studio tries to run it, it cannot run it because it is not the device owner.  Then i use ADB to make it the device owner and i can now run the updated version, but i still cannot debug as visual studio would no longer be connected to it.